# How to place footnote under TABLE in ConTeXt?

Tags: tables, footnotes, context, context-mkiv

I need to place footnotes, declared inside `\bTABLE` `\eTABLE`, just under the table, delimited with a short rule.

```
|----------|
|   table  |
|----------|
_______
 *footnote
```

I also need to `\placetable` this table correctly.

This

```
\usemodule  [simplefonts][size=12pt]
\setmainfont[dejavusans][expansion=quality,protrusion=quality]
\setupTABLE[frame=on,offset=1mm]

\starttext

\startlocalfootnotes
\placetable[right,none]{}{
  \bTABLE
  \bTR \bTD text \eTD
       \bTD other \footnote{text} \eTD \eTR
  \bTR \bTD[nc=2] very long \footnote{not very} text \eTD \eTR
  \eTABLE
  \placelocalfootnotes
}
\stoplocalfootnotes

\stoptext
```

variant does not work.  `\placefigure` just doing nothing. The table is not aligned to right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All floating environments expect a `\hbox`. When you use `\bTABLE .. \eTABLE \placelocalfootnotes` you create a `\vbox` that messes up alignment. So, the solution is wrap everything in a `\hbox`. You can also use `legends` to create a semantic layer for the footnotes (and can later change the style and color using `\setuplegend`. Here is a complete example:

```
\setuplegend[before=\startlocalfootnotes, after=\stoplocalfootnotes]

\starttext

  \startplacetable[location={right,none}]
    \hbox{\startplacelegend
        \startcontent
          \bTABLE
          \bTR 
             \bTD text \eTD 
             \bTD other \footnote{text} \eTD 
          \eTR
          \bTR 
             \bTD[nc=2] very long \footnote{not very} text \eTD 
          \eTR
          \eTABLE
        \stopcontent
        \startcaption
          \placelocalfootnotes
        \stopcaption
    \stopplacelegend}
  \stopplacefigure

\input knuth

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]